# How to exit out of the shell script successfully so that python subprocess think it is successfull exit?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, python, exit

Below is my shell script which simply execute a url like this `http://example.com:8080/beat` and parse the response and verify certain conditions on it. If that condition is met, then exit successfully out of the shell script using `exit 0`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

COUNT=60 
SUM_SYNCS=0
SUM_SYNCS_BEHIND=0
HOSTNAME=$hostname  

echo $HOSTNAME

while [[ $COUNT -ge "0" ]]; do

#send the request, put response in variable
DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/beat)

#grep $DATA for syncs and syncs_behind
SYNCS=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'num_syncs: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')
SYNCS_BEHIND=$(echo $DATA | grep -oE 'num_syncs_behind: [0-9]+' | awk '{print $2}')

echo $SYNCS
echo $SYNCS_BEHIND

#verify conditionals
if [[ $SYNCS -gt "8" && $SYNCS_BEHIND -eq "0" ]]; then exit 0; fi

#decrement the counter
let COUNT-=1

#wait another 10 seconds
sleep 10

done
```

I am able to execute the above shell script from Python subprocess module successfully as shown below -

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(shell_script, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, executable='/bin/bash') 
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode != 0:
    # log an error here
else:
    # success log here
```

But what is happening here is -  If you see my shell script I am exiting out of the shell script using `exit 0` which is a successful exit I guess and somehow in my Python code, it is logging an error after executing that shell script? Meaning it is going inside if statement somehow.

So is there any way, I can replace `exit 0` with some other successful exit call in shell script so that Python script can identify that, it's a successfull exit?

I don't want to modify Python script code..

Comment: `exit 0` **is** a successful exit. If the Python code says otherwise then either your script isn't returning with `exit 0` after all, or there's a bug in a part of the Python script you didn't show. Add `set -x` to your script to make it log what it's doing, maybe some command is failing before `exit 0` is hit. If you want further help, post complete code that we can run on our machine.

Comment: let me try adding `set -x` in my shell script and then run it again. I have provided the full shell script code and python code which I provided is the only code which is making a call to shell script.. Only the url I haven't provided full and it will not work outside my company firewall so that is the reason I didn't provided.

Comment: Can you show what is the value of `proc.returncode`. It is possible for instance that the return code is 127 if the python code can't find location of your shell script.

Comment: @Ketan: That's a good point.. Let me find out that as well.

Comment: It's part of your job when writing the question to provide runnable code if you want debugging help… For example, including the `import` directives in the Python fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the `set -e`:

> Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a subshell command enclosed in parentheses, or one of the commands executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.

Thus almost every command can make the script exit with a non-zero exit code.

A special problem you are maybe not aware of: The `let COUNT-=1` has exit code 1 if the result is 0. I.e. if the script has not executed `exit 0` before then it must fail.

You can solve this problem e.g. with:

```
let COUNT-=1 || true
```

But the main question is, of course: What is the `set -e` doing there? And who uses that without understanding the consequences...

Comment: I think OP edited the question and added `set -e`. It wasn't in the original script OP posted IIRC.

Comment: @Ketan That would be really evil. But I don't see the hint (and link to the revision list) when it has been edited. AFAIK this happens only if you edit a few seconds / (very few) minutes after posting.

Comment: my bad, I had it scrolled down and did not see/paste the top two lines while trying to reproduce.

Comment: @Ketan No problem, I accept your upvote...